# Using VB Update does not update my database

Tags: vb.net

My insert code works, but my update does not work "correctly". When my title textbox entry matches what is in the title database column it is supposed to update that entry, it follows through and the message box pops up "Entry updated" but it does not update.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click
    Dim sql As String

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\TylerPhillipsIP1.mdb"

    con.Open()

    Try
        sql = "INSERT INTO Books([Title], [Author], [Artist], [Chapter Number], [Page Number], [Genre])  VALUES('" & Me.TxtTitle.Text & "','" & Me.TxtAuthor.Text & "','" & Me.TxtArtist.Text & "','" & Me.TxtChapterNumber.Text & "','" & Me.TxtPageNumber.Text & "','" & Me.TxtGenre.Text & "')"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Entry Saved")
    Catch ex As Exception
        sql = "UPDATE Books SET [Author]=@Author, [Artist]=@Artist, [Chapter Number]=@Chapter_Number, [Page Number]=@Page_Number, [Genre]=@Genre WHERE [Title]=@Title;"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TxtTitle.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", TxtAuthor.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", TxtArtist.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chapter_Number", (TxtChapterNumber.Text).ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page_Number", (TxtPageNumber.Text).ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", TxtGenre.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Entry Updated")
    Finally
        TxtTitle.Text = ""
        TxtAuthor.Text = ""
        TxtArtist.Text = ""
        TxtChapterNumber.Text = ""
        TxtPageNumber.Text = ""
        TxtGenre.Text = ""

        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Thats not quite the right way to use Exceptions - not *everything* that can go wrong means that the data already exists.  The INSERT query should use Parameters as the UPDATE does.  How do you know it doesnt add?  Are you sure you are looking at the right DB?  If the DB is part of your project, you might be using a fresh new copy each time it runs.

Comment: You're not trying to update it with the same values are you? As far as your code stands, it looks like it should work properly, though poorly.

Comment: Plutonix when it "updates" it doesn't change the value nor does it add a new one. I am looking at the right DB because when I do add new ones they show up plus its the only one I got.

Comment: EBrown The purpose of my project is a bookmarking system so for some of the values I am updating the same but the ones that need to change are the chapter number and page number

Answer (score 0):

For sake of this exercise I will not optimize/parametarize your code. I will show how to know if the update really worked. I am afraid that you having issues with your `where` condition. Lets refactor your code a bit - And read comments in code!

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\TylerPhillipsIP1.mdb"

con.Open()

sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM Books WHERE [Title]=@Title;"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
dim result as integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

If result = 0 Then  

    sql = "INSERT INTO Books([Title], [Author], [Artist], [Chapter Number], [Page Number], [Genre])  VALUES('" & Me.TxtTitle.Text & "','" & Me.TxtAuthor.Text & "','" & Me.TxtArtist.Text & "','" & Me.TxtChapterNumber.Text & "','" & Me.TxtPageNumber.Text & "','" & Me.TxtGenre.Text & "')"
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    ' If the row inserted, the result will be > 0
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If result > 0 Then 
        MsgBox("Insert Success")
    Else
        MsgBox("Insert Failure")
    End if

Else

    sql = "UPDATE Books SET [Author]=@Author, [Artist]=@Artist, [Chapter Number]=@Chapter_Number, [Page Number]=@Page_Number, [Genre]=@Genre WHERE [Title]=@Title;"
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TxtTitle.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", TxtAuthor.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", TxtArtist.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Chapter_Number", (TxtChapterNumber.Text).ToString())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page_Number", (TxtPageNumber.Text).ToString())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", TxtGenre.Text)
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ' For the UPDATE, this is the key - to check if anything was updated. Because UPDATE is naturally will not throw any errors and you will not ever know, unless you send bad data or try to duplicate a unique key.
    If result > 0 Then 
        MsgBox("Update Success")
    Else
        MsgBox("Update Failure")
    End if


    con.Close()

End If
```

For the purpose of this exercise, I am omitting how you handle the errors, parametrization and control data flow. I want to show that if you take `result` after update and its value is `>0` - you did in fact updated the row. Only for some treason you don't know about it. If the result is `0`, you didn't update. Then, you need to see what is in your where: `WHERE [Title]=@Title`. May be you updating title that doesn't exist. Unless you check the return of `ExecuteNonQuery` when you doing DB Update, you can't really tell if you updated or not. I hope this will help you